# Loading a picturebox image from a byte array in VB6

Tags: vb6, picturebox

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279221/convert-a-picture-box-image-to-a-byte-array-in-vb6) explains nicely how to convert a picture box image to a byte array in VB6.
I want to do the reverse and load my picture box image from a byte array.

I have found a partial solution  [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?493209-How-to-display-a-byte-array-bitmap-on-Picturebox)  which uses the following code

```
Public Function ArrayToPicture(inArray() As Byte, Offset As Long, Size As Long) As IPicture

    ' function creates a stdPicture from the passed array
    ' Offset is first item in array: 0 for 0 bound arrays
    ' Size is how many bytes comprise the image
    Dim o_hMem  As Long
    Dim o_lpMem  As Long
    Dim aGUID(0 To 3) As Long
    Dim IIStream As IUnknown

    aGUID(0) = &H7BF80980    ' GUID for stdPicture
    aGUID(1) = &H101ABF32
    aGUID(2) = &HAA00BB8B
    aGUID(3) = &HAB0C3000

    o_hMem = GlobalAlloc(&H2&, Size)
    If Not o_hMem = 0& Then
        o_lpMem = GlobalLock(o_hMem)
        If Not o_lpMem = 0& Then
            CopyMemory ByVal o_lpMem, inArray(Offset), Size
            Call GlobalUnlock(o_hMem)
            If CreateStreamOnHGlobal(o_hMem, 1&, IIStream) = 0& Then
                  Call OleLoadPicture(ByVal ObjPtr(IIStream), 0&, 0&, aGUID(0), ArrayToPicture)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

How do I get the Offset and Size to pass to this function?

Comment: Try 0 and ubound(yourarray) to tell it the array entire is the image

Comment: I used Offset = LBound(Bytear()) and size = UBound(Bytear()) - LBound(Bytear()) +1 It seems to work, I wonder why the sample doesn't just do that? Care to write up your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Size` argument is the total number of bytes that comprise the image in the array, `Offset` is the index of the array where the data begins, this allows a single array to store multiple images.

If the array contains a single image only, pass it's `LBound` for `Offset` and `UBound - LBound + 1` for `Size`.