# Converting 32x32 StdPicture icons to PNG

Tags: arrays, vb6, png

I am trying to convert an StdPicture into a PNG before encoding it to Base64 to be sent over XML. I've gotten the Base64 encoding portion down (see near end of function `EncodeImageToBase64()`) however I am having trouble converting the StdPicture object into a PNG byte array.

Here's my function:

```
Private Function EncodeImageToBase64(ByRef Image As StdPicture) As String
  Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument60
  Dim xmlNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
  Dim bColor() As Byte
  Dim bMask() As Byte
  Dim bImage() As Byte
  Dim lCrcTable() As Long
  Dim lWidth As Long
  Dim lHeight As Long
  EncodeImageToBase64 = vbNullString

  If Image Is Nothing Then
    Exit Function
  End If

  Call MakeCRC32Table(lCrcTable)
  Call IconPicToArrays(Image, bColor, bMask, lWidth, lHeight)
  If Not CreatePngByteArray(bImage, lWidth, lHeight, bColor, bMask, lCrcTable) Then
    Debug.Assert False
    Exit Function
  End If
  'Call GetPictureBits(bImage, Image)

  Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument60
  Set xmlNode = xmlDoc.createElement("b64")
  xmlNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
  xmlNode.nodeTypedValue = bImage
  EncodeImageToBase64 = xmlNode.Text

  Set xmlNode = Nothing
  Set xmlDoc = Nothing
End Function
```

The problem is that the people who wrote CreatePngByteArray only intended the function to convert PNG's of 16x16. Thus my 32x32 icons fail the assertion that's in the function:

```
'Create PNG (RFC-2083) image based on a 16x16 icon's color and mask bitmaps
Public Function CreatePngByteArray(ByRef bTarget() As Byte, ByVal Width As Long, ByVal _
      Height As Long, bColor() As Byte, bMask() As Byte, lCrcTable() As Long) As Boolean
  Dim bIndex() As Byte
  Dim bPalette() As Byte
  Dim lPos As Long
  Dim lCRC As Long
  Dim X As Long
  Dim Y As Long
  Dim z As Long
  Dim lPalSize As Long

  If Width > 16 Or Height > 16 Then Exit Function

  lPalSize = RGBtoPalette(bColor, bMask, bIndex, bPalette, Width, Height)

  ReDim bTarget(0 To 364 + lPalSize) As Byte '8+25+(12+lPalSize)+13+295+12-1

  'PNG signature 'long val = -1991225785  'hex value = 89504E47
  bTarget(0) = 137
  bTarget(1) = 80
  bTarget(2) = 78
  bTarget(3) = 71
  bTarget(4) = 13
  bTarget(5) = 10
  bTarget(6) = 26
  bTarget(7) = 10
  lPos = 8

  'IHDR
  Call FlipLongToArray(13, bTarget(), lPos)
  Call FlipLongToArray(pctIHDR, bTarget(), lPos + 4) 'add chunk flag
  Call FlipLongToArray(Width, bTarget(), lPos + 8)
  Call FlipLongToArray(Height, bTarget(), lPos + 12)
  bTarget(lPos + 16) = 8  'bit depth
  bTarget(lPos + 17) = 3  'color type
  bTarget(lPos + 18) = 0  'compression - none
  bTarget(lPos + 19) = 0  'filter
  bTarget(lPos + 20) = 0  'interlace
  lCRC = CRC32(bTarget(), lPos + 4, lPos + 20, lCrcTable())
  Call FlipLongToArray(lCRC, bTarget(), lPos + 21)
  lPos = lPos + 25

  'PLTE
  Call FlipLongToArray(lPalSize, bTarget(), lPos)
  Call FlipLongToArray(pctPLTE, bTarget(), lPos + 4)   'add chunk flag
  Call CopyMemory(bTarget(lPos + 8), bPalette(0), lPalSize)
  lCRC = CRC32(bTarget(), lPos + 4, lPos + lPalSize + 7, lCrcTable())
  Call FlipLongToArray(lCRC, bTarget(), lPos + lPalSize + 8)
  lPos = lPos + lPalSize + 12

  'tRNS
  Call FlipLongToArray(1, bTarget(), lPos)
  Call FlipLongToArray(pcttRNS, bTarget(), lPos + 4)  'add chunk flag
  bTarget(lPos + 8) = 0 'alpha
  lCRC = CRC32(bTarget(), lPos + 4, lPos + 8, lCrcTable())
  Call FlipLongToArray(lCRC, bTarget(), lPos + 9)
  lPos = lPos + 13

  'IDAT
  Call FlipLongToArray(283, bTarget(), lPos)
  Call FlipLongToArray(pctIDAT, bTarget(), lPos + 4)  'add chunk flag
  bTarget(lPos + 8) = 24 '8=deflate + 16=512b LZ77 window (RFC-1950)
  bTarget(lPos + 9) = 25 'so that (CompMethod*256 + AddlFlags) Mod 31=0 (RFC-1950)
  bTarget(lPos + 10) = 1 '(RFC-1951)
  bTarget(lPos + 11) = 16 '272: LEN 0 (RFC-1951)
  bTarget(lPos + 12) = 1 '272: LEN 1
  bTarget(lPos + 13) = &HEF '~272: NLEN 0 (RFC-1951)
  bTarget(lPos + 14) = &HFE '~272: NLEN 1
  For X = 0 To 15
    bTarget(lPos + 15 + z) = 0
    Call CopyMemory(bTarget(lPos + 16 + z), bIndex(Y), 16)
    Y = Y + 16
    z = z + 17
  Next X
  lCRC = Adler32(bTarget(), lPos + 15, lPos + 286)
  Call FlipLongToArray(lCRC, bTarget(), lPos + 287) 'Adler32 is supposed to be safe to leave empty, but isn't
  lCRC = CRC32(bTarget(), lPos + 4, lPos + 290, lCrcTable())
  Call FlipLongToArray(lCRC, bTarget(), lPos + 291)
  lPos = lPos + 295

  'IEND
  Call FlipLongToArray(0, bTarget(), lPos)
  Call FlipLongToArray(pctIEND, bTarget(), lPos + 4)   'add chunk flag
  lCRC = CRC32(bTarget(), lPos + 4, lPos + 7, lCrcTable())
  Call FlipLongToArray(lCRC, bTarget(), lPos + 8)

  CreatePngByteArray = True
End Function
```

I've looked over this code relentlessly but I have not done very much low-level programming (dealing with bytes and whatnot) and have come up far short.

Is there any way to repurpose this, or any other way to be able to convert PNG images of any size into byte arrays? If I'm going to be using libraries /.dlls I prefer they be standard Microsoft ones.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279221/convert-a-picture-box-image-to-a-byte-array-in-vb6

Comment: OK, so I see that what you need is to convert your StdPicture to a PNG before sending it away. I hate to suggest already made-up code, and it may be overkill for what you need, but have you heard of [LaVolpe's GDI+ classes for VB6](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=67466&lngWId=1)? The code is quite a few years old ([it evolved into a user control](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?630193-vb6-Alpha-Image-Control-v2-Final-Update-%2815-Jan-2012%29)), but if you need a readily available solution, it could serve you well.

Comment: Or, you could always rewrite `CreatePngByteArray()` to work with 32x32 images instead. If you keep in mind that the code assumes being fed a byte array for a 16x16 picture of a predefined format, it would be good exercise to do (I'd try myself, but then I'd have to fill the blanks, namely `Adler()`& `RGBtoPalette()`...) For instance, the first 8 bytes are for the PNG signature (big endian), then 13 is the size of the IHDR chunk (excl. itself, chunk type & CRC), followed by the signature of the chunk (0x52444849 or 'RDHI', as `pctIHDR`), the IHDR data (13 bytes) ending with the CRC of sig+data.

Comment: For the IDTA chunk, the size of `283` (excl. size DWORD, chunk sign. & final CRC) comes from `7 + [16 x (16+1)] + 4 (Adler32)`. For a 32x32 image, it will probably be `7 + [32 x (32+1)] + 4 (Adler32)` or 1067 bytes (with filter method 0, a filter-type byte must be prepended to each scanline). The palette chunk (PLTE) shouldn't change, unless you change bit depth (8 bits=256-color palette) or color type (3=indexed palette) of your PNG. To better understand the remaining code yourself, you can refer to the [PNG specification](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Contents.html). Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a property bag like this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim encoded     As String

    encoded = EncodeImageToBase64(LoadPicture("d:\temp\aaa.gif"))
    Caption = "Encoded Size: " & Len(encoded)
    Set Picture = DecodeImageFromBase64(encoded)
End Sub

Private Function EncodeImageToBase64(ByRef Image As StdPicture) As String
    Dim oBag        As PropertyBag

    Set oBag = New PropertyBag
    oBag.WriteProperty "i", Image, Nothing
    With VBA.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument").createElement("dummy")
        .DataType = "bin.base64"
        .NodeTypedValue = oBag.Contents
        EncodeImageToBase64 = .Text
    End With
End Function

Private Function DecodeImageFromBase64(ByRef Base64 As String) As StdPicture
    Dim oBag        As PropertyBag
    Dim QH          As Long

    On Error GoTo QH
    Set oBag = New PropertyBag
    With VBA.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument").createElement("dummy")
        .DataType = "bin.base64"
        .Text = Base64
        oBag.Contents = .NodeTypedValue
    End With
    Set DecodeImageFromBase64 = oBag.ReadProperty("i", Nothing)
QH:
End Function
```