# How to Convert BMP Image in PictureBox to Array of Bytes in VB6

Tags: arrays, vb6, picturebox, memorystream, bmp

In a legacy VB6 application I have a BMP image stored in a PictureBox.  I am able to save it to a BMP file using:

```
  SavePicture picBox.Picture, "BmpImage.bmp"
```

However what I want is to save the BMP image in the PictureBox to an array of bytes.  I need the entire BMP to be stored including the BMP headers.  Effectively I want the same data that would be written to the BMP file but in a Byte array and without having to write and read a disk file.

I've searched but have not found anything online that addresses this particular question.

---

I did find one [link](https://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/358059-how-get-picture-into-byte-array) that suggested writing to a MemoryStream.  So I tried this:

```
10  Dim bmpArray() As Byte
20  Dim memStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream

50  SavePicture picBox.Picture, memStream
60  bmpArray = memStream.GetBuffer
```

However this doesn't compile.  I get *"User-defined type not defined"* for "System.IO.MemoryStream"  I've included System in my list of references.  I've also tried declaring as **New MemoryStream** but still get the "User-defeind type not defined" compiler error.

---

Also I have looked at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279221/convert-a-picture-box-image-to-a-byte-array-in-vb6) however the solution provided only stores the pixel data in the array.

Comment: The code you're attempting to use is for VB.Net, thus the error...

Comment: JonN, @Idle_Mind was referring to the memorystream code. That doesn't exist in VB6.

Comment: If you have the option to write .NET code, you could possibly create a VB.NET class which does whatever you want, and call that from VB6. There's some initial setup overhead in getting that to work of course, plus whatever deployment changes you'd have to make.

Comment: @Idle_Mind yes I suspected that it was because the 1st link was a solution for .NET but thought I'd try it and see if MemoryStream was available in VB6.   I'm hoping someone here knows how to create equivalent of a memory stream in VB6 or some other way to convert PictureBox to array of bytes.

Comment: Do some searches.  There is a lot of code around for doing this in VB6, but it isn't the kind of thing easily posted here because there are a lot of little steps and each should have error checking as you go.  This site is better suited to simple Q & A rather than requesting code samples aside from tiny ones.

Comment: @Bob77 As stated in my original question "I've searched but have not found anything online that addresses this particular question. "   I only came here after much searching for an online solution to no avail.

You seem to be saying that the solution to converting PictureBox to in memory BMP is not simple.  All the more reason to come here .  If you know of an online solution please provide link.

Comment: Here is the first link I found: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?808301-VB6-PicSave-Simple-SavePicture-as-GIF-PNG-JPEG

Comment: That vbforums.com link does not address my question.  As it states in the posting

"It saves to disk, not to Byte arrays."

I'm looking for the opposite.  There is already a simple call for saving BMP to disk as I showed in my question.        

 SavePicture picBox.Picture, "BmpImage.bmp"

Answer (score 1):

If you literally want the exact contents of the BMP file as an array of bytes, why not do it in steps?

Step 1: Use SavePicture to write to a temporary file.

Step 2: Use normal file I/O operations to read the temporary file back into an array.

Step 3: Delete the temp file

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing as a "work around".  However as I stated in my question, I want to do this without having to write to a temp file.  I have to believe there is a way to do this in VB6 without resorting to writing to disk.

Comment: Why do you consider this to be a workaround? The in-memory format of an image in the PictuteBox is probably not the same as the binary representation do the same image in Bitmap format. And in fact there are multiple variations of what can be in a "BMP" format.

Comment: It's a workaround because one of the requirements for this scenario in my application is avoiding writing to disk.  The whole point of the new feature being added is to eliminating disk writes.

Comment: Fair enough... curious though what the restriction on writing to disk?

Comment: In an earlier version of the project two components exchanged images via disk files.  One of those components is my application (ActiveX EXE in VB6) The other component which my application delivers images to is from 3rd party.  A more recent version of the 3rd party component now accepts images directly through memory.  This was done to speedup the image exchange.  So to have to write the image to disk in order to get it into memory defeats the intended design improvement.  The 3rd party is expecting my app to deliver the image directly in memory without wasting time writing to disk.

Answer (score 1):

There are functions in `GDI32` that make it simple to get an array from an image. I can't post working code here because I've written much of it in assembly using custom Types etc, but I can tell you to start your search at `GetDIBits()`, where the 'DI' stands for Device Independent.

Here's a declaration for it:

```
Public Declare Sub GetDIBits Lib "gdi32" _
 (ByVal hDC As Long, _
  ByVal hBitmap As Long, _
  ByVal nStartScan As Long, _
  ByVal nNumScans As Long, _
  ByRef lpBits As Any, _
  ByRef lpBI As BITMAPINFO, _
  ByVal wUsage As Long)
```

Use the `.hDC` of the picture box.

You'll need definitions for `BITMAPINFO`, `BITMAPINFOHEADER` etc but it sounds as if you may already have those.

Comment: I looked up GetDIBits and it appears to have a variety of behaviors based on the input parameters provided.  I don't see a straightforward call scenario that would return the entire BMP array including headers and pixel data as an array of bytes.   At best it looks like you would need to retrieve the BMP header, palette and pixel data separately and assemble them somehow into an array of bytes yourself.  Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @JonN - You can create your array with the headers in place, then point GetDIBits at the place in the array where the data belongs. Done. Aside from writing/reading as a file or pipe I don't know any way to get the BMP header built for you.

Comment: Don't the headers vary in size depending on the particular BMP format being used?  Aren't there two different versions of the header and the palette section can vary in size too, Right?  So would the technique be to read in some portion of the header and then from that determine the sizes of the various headers and select the position in the array for each section accordingly?